# neural net: bias seems to be ignored

Tags: java, xor, bias-neuron

I coded a very simple neural net with 1 neuron and 2 inputs and 1 bias in java, trying to classify dots on either the left or right side of a line. The problem is that the neural net recognizes the slope of the line but not the y-intercept (e.g. the function of the line may be y = m*x + c and the NN recognizes the m but not the c).

I tried to use a bias value=1 in order to enable the NN to calculate the weight for the bias which should be the y-intercept. But it doesnt. You will see that I am very new to Java programming. Unfortunately also new to NN. In that case I guess my problem is rather in the understanding of the underlying methodology of the bias in the NN.

Remark: In the output line at the very end of the code, I would expect in case of the function y = 3*x + 5 following figures: weight[0]=3 (which is the m) , weight[1]=1 (which is the factor for y) and weight[2]=5 (this is c). The weight[2] is always wrong.

```
package nn2;
public class anfang_eng {

public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    double[][] points = new double[5][10000];
    double[] weights = new double[3];
    double[][] normpoints = new double[5][10000];


//  create 1000 dots with desired result for training afterwards
    points = createPoints();

//  the before randomly created x and y values of the 1000 dots
//  shall be normalized between 0 and 1
    normpoints = normalize(points);

//  create two random initial weights
    weights = createinitialWeights();

//  training function, calculation of three different weights
    calculateWeights(normpoints, weights);
    testnewPoints(weights); 
}

//  thats the function of the line, that seperates all dots in
// two groups: all the dots at the left side of the line and all the dots 
// at the right side. 

static double function(double x, double y)
{
    double result;
    result = 3*x - y + 5;
    return result;
}


static double[][] createPoints() 
{
//  1. step: lets create for training reasons some dots and calculate
// the result for each dot (result is either "1" or "-1").
//  point[0] is x, point[1] is y, point[2] is bias and point[3] is
// result (left or right side of the function above

int x;
int y;
int quantity= 1000; 
double[][] point = new double[5][quantity];

for (int i=0; i<quantity; i++)
    {
    x =  (int) (2000 * Math.random()-1000);
    y =  (int) (2000 * Math.random()-1000);     
    point[0][i] = x;
    point[1][i] = y;
//  point[2] is our bias
    point[2][i] = 1;

// all dots which are at the right side of the function above get
// result "1". otherwise "-1"
        if ( function(x,y) > 0)
            point[3][i] = 1;
        else
            point[3][i] =-1;
// point[3] contains  the result    
    }
// in the variable point, there are e.g. 1000 or 5000 dots with x, y,
// bias and the result (1=left side and -1=right side) 
    return point;
}



//  normalize x and y values between 0 and 1
static double[][] normalize(double[][]points)
{
    int quantity = points[0].length;
    double minpoint_x=1000;
    double minpoint_y=1000; 
    double maxpoint_x=-1000;
    double maxpoint_y=-1000;        

    double[][] normpoints = new double[5][quantity];
    minpoint_x= points[0][0];
    minpoint_y = points[1][0];
    maxpoint_x = points[0][0];
    maxpoint_y = points[1][0];

    for (int i=0; i<quantity;i++)
    {
            if (points[0][i]<minpoint_x)    
                    minpoint_x=points[0][i];
            if (points[1][i]<minpoint_y) 
                    minpoint_y=points[1][i];
            if (points[0][i]>maxpoint_x)
                    maxpoint_x=points[0][i];
            if (points[1][i]>maxpoint_y) 
                    maxpoint_y=points[1][i];                    
    }

    for (int u=0; u<quantity; u++)
    {
        normpoints [0][u]= (points[0][u]-minpoint_x)/(maxpoint_x-minpoint_x);
        normpoints [1][u]= (points[1][u]-minpoint_y)/(maxpoint_y-minpoint_y);
        normpoints [2][u] = 1; //bias is always 1
        normpoints [3][u] = points[3][u];
    }   


return normpoints;
}



static double[] createinitialWeights()
{   
//  creation of initial weights between -1 and 1
    double[] weight = new double[3];    
    weight[0] =   2*Math.random()-1;
    weight[1] =   2*Math.random()-1;        
    weight[2] =   2*Math.random()-1;

    return weight;
}





static void calculateWeights(double[][] normpoints, double[] weight)
//  new weight = weight + error * input * learning constant
//  c is learning constant 
{
    double c = 0.01;
    double error = 0;
    double sumguess = 0;
    double guess = 0;
    int quantity = normpoints[0].length;


    for (int i=0; i < quantity; i++)
    {

// normpoint[0][i] stands for the factor at x, normpoint[0][i] is
// for y and normpoint[2][i] is for bias 

    sumguess = normpoints[0][i] * weight[0] + normpoints[1][i]*weight[1] + normpoints[2][i]*weight[2];
        if (sumguess > 0)
            guess = 1;
        else 
            guess = -1;

        error =  normpoints[3][i]- guess;


        weight[0] = weight[0] + error * normpoints[0][i] * c;
        weight[1] = weight[1] + error * normpoints[1][i] * c;
        weight[2] = weight[2] + error * normpoints[2][i] * c;

        System.out.println("i: " + i + " ;value_normpoint[0]:" + normpoints[0][i]+ " ;value_normpoint[1]" + normpoints[1][i]+ " ;value_normpoint[2]" + normpoints[2][i] + " result:" + normpoints[3][i]);
        System.out.println("weight[0]: " + Math.round(weight[0]*100)/100.0 + " ;weight[1]: " +Math.round(weight[1]*100)/100.0 + " ;weight[2]: " + Math.round(weight[2]*100)/100.0 );
        System.out.println("guess: "+ guess+ " result " + normpoints[3][i] + " error: " + error);
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("final weights:  x: " + weight[0] + " y: "+ weight[1] + " bias: " +weight[2]);
    System.out.println("final weights normalized on y=1:   x:" + weight[0]/weight[1] + "  y: "+ weight[1]/weight[1] + " bias: " +weight[2]/weight[1]);

}


//  lets test if the trained weights classify the test dot on the correct side of the line y=4*x+3
// again 500 random dots with "x", "y" and "results" are created and tested if the NN calculated correct weights
static void testnewPoints(double[] weights)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    double[][] testpoint = new double[5][10000];
    double[][] normalizedtestpoint = new double[5][10000];
    int quantity = 500;

    double sumcheck = 0;
    double sumtest = 0;
    int correct = 0;
    int wrong = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<quantity; i++)
        {

//  calculation of test points with x and y between -100 and 100
        x =  (int) (200 * Math.random()-100);
        y =  (int) (200 * Math.random()-100);   
        testpoint[0][i] = x;
        testpoint[1][i] = y;
        testpoint[2][i] = 1;

// lets classify the points: at the rights side of the line the result for each point is "1", on the left side "-1"
        if (function(x,y) > 0)
            testpoint[3][i] = 1;
        else
            testpoint[3][i] = -1;
//  punkt[3] is the result

        }

        normalizedtestpoint= normalize(testpoint);
//      are the test points with our calculated weights classified on the correct side of the line? 
        for (int i=0; i<quantity; i++)
        {
            sumcheck = normalizedtestpoint[0][i] * weights[0] + normalizedtestpoint[1][i] * weights[1] + normalizedtestpoint[2][i] * weights[2];                
            if (sumcheck > 0)
                sumtest = 1;
            else 
                sumtest = -1;
            if (sumtest == normalizedtestpoint[3][i])
                    correct++;
            else
                wrong++;
        }
        System.out.println("correct: "+ correct + " wrong: " + wrong);
}
}
```

Please let me also know if you see some major issues in my coding style, quite an beginner style I guess.
Many thanks in advance!
Lonko